# Is SecureUDID resident between uninstalls and reinstalls?

Tags: objective-c, ios, apple-push-notifications

Is SecureUDID resident between uninstalls and reinstalls? It's written that UIPasteboards are deleted when application is uninstalled (http://www.secureudid.org/). I want the exact same Id even if user deletes and reinstalls the app.

Comment: Have you looked into the keychain? That doesn't reset between installs.

Answer (score 1):

Like Richard J. Ross said: I have used the Keychain's application-shared secure storage to store an app-generated UUID. It stays there after an uninstall (even if no other apps are installed and sharing the storage).

FWIW, it does appear that SecureUDID will not survive a delete, but I am not familiar with that project.